# Typo3 7.6.2 - missing the RealURL option "Override the whole page path "

Tags: typo3, realurl

I have Typo3 7.6.2 and RealURL 1.13.15, whis is for Typo3 4.5.40-7.9.999

In Typo3  < 7 there was option "Override the whole page path "

In Typo3 7.6.2 seems this option is not present.

In the language file of RealUrl is:

```
<label index="pages.tx_realurl_path_override">Override the whole page path</label>
```

But in BE of Typo3 i can't find this option

My config is:

```
'realurl' => 'a:5:{s:10:"configFile";s:26:"typo3conf/realurl_conf.php";s:14:"enableAutoConf";s:1:"1";s:14:"autoConfFormat";s:1:"0";s:12:"enableDevLog";s:1:"0";s:19:"enableChashUrlDebug";s:1:"0";}'
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look into `typo3conf/ext/realurl/ext_tables.php:78` there are these lines which according to @deprecated comment in `typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Utility/ExtensionManagementUtility.php:318` in version 7.x+ as I hardly believe should be replaced:

```
$extensionMamagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes('pages', 'tx_realurl_pathsegment;;137;;,tx_realurl_exclude', '1', 'after:nav_title');
$extensionMamagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes('pages', 'tx_realurl_pathsegment;;137;;,tx_realurl_exclude', '4,199,254', 'after:title');
```

with:

```
$extensionMamagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes('pages', 'tx_realurl_pathsegment, --palette--;;137, tx_realurl_exclude', '1', 'after:nav_title');
$extensionMamagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes('pages', 'tx_realurl_pathsegment, --palette--;;137, tx_realurl_exclude', '4,199,254', 'after:title');
```

You can probably override the TCA within your own ext, or just hack the RealURL source (dirty solution) anyway must accent that I have no idea what is Dmitry's intension. (In other words I don't know if ***it's bug, or a feature*** ;))

Comment: I don't know too :-). You have small typo in _extensionMamagementUtility_ **extensionManagementUtility** Because of I am using composer mode, I overrided it with my own ext

Comment: It's Dmitry's Typo :-) in typo3conf/ext/realurl/ext_tables.php:77-82 
`$extensionMamagementUtility::addFieldsToPalette('pages', '3', 'tx_realurl_nocache', 'after:cache_timeout');
$extensionMamagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes('pages', 'tx_realurl_pathsegment;;137;;,tx_realurl_exclude', '1', 'after:nav_title');
$extensionMamagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes('pages', 'tx_realurl_pathsegment;;137;;,tx_realurl_exclude', '4,199,254', 'after:title');

$extensionMamagementUtility::addLLrefForTCAdescr('pages','EXT:realurl/locallang_csh.xml');`
Ma  _m_  agement may be Ma  **n**  agement

Comment: Yes, _extensionMamagementUtility_ it's original spelling, anyway it doesn't matter while using constantly ;)